# What is the relation between $\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i^T$ and the covariance matrix?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, covariance, sampling

Suppose $x$ is a random vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which is distributed according to $D$.

Assume $x_i$ is a sample.

> What is $\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i^T$?
>
> How can I relate this to covariance of data $C$?
>
> Is $\sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i^T = \alpha C +\beta$ for some $\alpha$ and $\beta$?
>
> Having $(x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N)$, how one can find $\mathbb{E}[(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T]$?

My try to answer the above are as follows:

When we have access to the sequence of data we can build

$$
X'_N=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_N
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Sample average is $\mu_N = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^N x_i}{N}$ so the normalized data matrix is

$$
X_N=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 -\mu_N  & x_2- \mu_N & \cdots & x_N-\mu_N
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore, $C_N$ is sample covariance matrix
$$
C_N=X_NX_N^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 -\mu_N  & x_2- \mu_N & \cdots & x_N-\mu_N
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
(x_1 -\mu_N)^T  \\ (x_2- \mu_N)^T \\ \cdots \\ (x_N-\mu_N)^T
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
C_N= (x_1 -\mu_N)(x_1 -\mu_N)^T + (x_2- \mu_N)(x_2- \mu_N)^T + \cdots + (x_N-\mu_N)(x_N-\mu_N)^T
$$

$$
C_N= \sum_{i=1}^N x_ix_i^T - (\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)\mu_N^T -\mu_N(\sum_{i=1}^N x_i)^T +N \mu_N\mu_N^T
$$

Please answer my four questions separately.

Comment: If the $x_i$ are iid then the easiest thing to do is to replace $\mu_N$ by $\mu$ and evaluate the variance of $C_N-C$ using that the $(x_i-\mu)^\top(x_i-\mu)$ are iid. With $\mu_N$ the $(x_i-\mu_N)^\top(x_i-\mu_N)$ are not iid not even unbiased anymore, which leads to the [unbiased estimator](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2019122/unbiased-estimate-of-the-covariance)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample covariance $C_N$ is
$$C_N=\frac1N\sum (x_i-\mu_N) (x_i-\mu_N)^T.$$

From there, you can do as you did to prove
$$C_N=\frac1N\sum x_i x_i^T -\frac1N \left(\sum x_i\right)\mu_N^T -\frac1N \mu_N \left(\sum x_i\right)^T+\mu_N \mu_N^T=$$
$$=\frac1N\sum x_i x_i^T-\mu_N \mu_N^T.$$

So you can find $\alpha$ and $\beta$ from here (although they will depend on the sample).

Finally, you can't "find" $E(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T$ (the actual covariance matrix of $x$) in terms of the sample, since this is a parameter of the distribution of $x$, but it can be shown (through the law of large numbers) that under fairly general conditions, $C_N$ is a consistent estimation for it.

Comment: In this post it is $\frac{1}{N-1}$ to make it unbiased, should I need that, can you explain it?